# Was VS Had Been

Tags: grammar

In writing a scientific article, referring to previous studies, what is more appropriate?

> A model based on XXX **was/had been** applied on said YYY and the results showed that...

I don't really grasp the difference between the two

Comment: *Something **was** done and... [this is what we have found, which is relevant to **current time of speaking***]. OR *Something **was** done and... [this is what we found **back then, immediately after it had been found***]. The second version would only normally be used if you specifically wanted to focus on *the point in past time **after** having done something*.

Comment: ...in your exact context you almost certainly want to use Simple Past, because *the results showed that [blah blah]* implies that the past application of the model is relevant to ***current time of speaking / writing***. You'd only normally use the Perfect form in such contexts if you wanted to continue the sentence by mentioning something else that took place in the past. Note that even though *the results **showed** that [blah blah]* is phrased as Past Tense, it would make no difference if we changed that to *...the results **show** that...* - it's not *really* a past tense reference.

Comment: Can you use real words instead of XXX and YYY? It's much easier for others to understand the intent. As it stands, I don't even know if the sentence is good grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can technically use either, but it depends on how you have formed the rest of the paragraph about this study.

"Was" is usually used to describe something that happened in the past and has ended, and "had been" is for something that had taken place and went on for a period of time.

If you are explaining details about the study and how it was conducted, then I would stick to "was".

If it's more of a brief description of one major detail in the study (i.e. just that one sentence you described), then you could use "had been".

However, being that you can use both, I do think that "was" sounds much better than had been because it is a scientific article which is less about using advanced sentence formulation and more about getting to the point.

You can read more about the differences [here](https://www.learnenglishteam.com/how-to-use-have-has-had-been/).